# finished with non-zero exit value 4

Tags: unity-game-engine

An error occurred while building the apk, how can I fix it?

Error: Unity.IL2CPP.Building.BuilderFailedException: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\23.1.7779620\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++ @"C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpAABC.tmp" -o "E:\testArabic\unityLibrary\build\il2cpp_armeabi-v7a_Release\il2cpp_cache\linkresult_D469FBEED00B862A759E3E8D5369FD17\libil2cpp.so" -shared -Wl,-soname,libil2cpp.so -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--build-id -stdlib=libc++ -static-libstdc++ -target armv7-linux-androideabi19 -Wl,--wrap,sigaction "E:\testArabic\unityLibrary\src\main\jniStaticLibs\armeabi-v7a\baselib.a" -llog -rdynamic -fuse-ld=gold.exe

clang++: error: invalid linker name in argument '-fuse-ld=gold.exe'

at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.PostprocessObjectFiles(HashSet`1 objectFiles, CppToolChainContext toolChainContext) at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.Build(IBuildStatistics& statistics) at il2cpp.Compilation.CompilationDriver.Run(RuntimePlatform platform, BuildingOptions buildingOptions, ReadOnlyCollection`1 matchedAssemblyMethodSourceFiles)
at il2cpp.Program.DoRun(String[] args, RuntimePlatform platform, BuildingOptions buildingOptions, Boolean throwExceptions)
Unity.IL2CPP.Building.BuilderFailedException: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\23.1.7779620\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++ @"C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpAABC.tmp" -o "E:\testArabic\unityLibrary\build\il2cpp_armeabi-v7a_Release\il2cpp_cache\linkresult_D469FBEED00B862A759E3E8D5369FD17\libil2cpp.so" -shared -Wl,-soname,libil2cpp.so -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--build-id -stdlib=libc++ -static-libstdc++ -target armv7-linux-androideabi19 -Wl,--wrap,sigaction "E:\testArabic\unityLibrary\src\main\jniStaticLibs\armeabi-v7a\baselib.a" -llog -rdynamic -fuse-ld=gold.exe

> Task :unityLibrary:BuildIl2CppTask FAILED

Comment: Using ndk r19 for 2020, r21d for 2021

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, it has been solved